# Save One-to-Many Relationship in Laravel 6

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relational-database

I have two Table that `Transfer` and `Product` that link `One-to-Many` Relationship. I'm to create relationship between `Transfer` and `Product` like Pics Below.

[image]

that get `Selected Dropdown` Product when Click Search.... and When Click Create save relationship Product into Transfers..

[image: pic 2]

**My Transfer Model**

```
    public function products()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(\App\Product::class);
    }
```

**My Product Model**

```
    public function transfer()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(\App\Transfer::class);
    }
```

**in TransferController**

```
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'from_location' => 'required',
            'to_location' => 'required',
            'status' => 'required',
            'description' => 'nullable',
            'shipping_charge' => 'nullable',
        ]);

        $transfer = new Transfer();
        $transfer->branch_id = auth()->user()->id;
        $transfer->from_location = $request->input('from_location');
        $transfer->to_location = $request->input('to_location');
        $transfer->status = $request->input('status');
        $transfer->shipping_charge = $request->input('shipping_charge');
        $transfer->save();

        // $products = new Product();
        // $products->name = $request->input('')

        return response()->json(['created' => true]);
    }
```

I think its a dummy question, but i stuck 3 days with it. I'll appreciate of all Ur help...

Answer (score 0):

You need to post the product_ids  to backend that you selected,

and just update the relationship:

```php
        ...
        $transfer->shipping_charge = $request->input('shipping_charge');
        $transfer->save();
        Product::whereIn('id', $product_ids)->update(['transfer_id' => $transfer->id]);
```

If your products are all new, you can use [saveMany](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#inserting-related-models):

```php
$products = array(
  new Product(['name' =>'product1', ...]),
  new Product(['name' => 'product2', ...])
);
...
$transfer->save();
$transfer->products()->saveMany($products);
```

Comment: bro, its got error like this `Use of undefined constant id - assumed 'id' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP)`

Comment: `$product_ids` where it come from? i got `Undefined variable: product_ids`

Comment: @z3r0 come from your frontend. the products you selected.

Comment: u the first person on stackoverflow for me that answer the question and ask does it work? xD

Comment: @z3r0 so say it.

Comment: bro, is there a way reach u directly, i want to screenshot my problem to u.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204893/discussion-between-z3r0-and-tsaikoga).